# CliBuilder Arguments Are Empty

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface

Here's a working example of my problem:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'cli-test -d <argument>')

cli.with {
  h(longOpt: 'help', 'usage information')
  d(longOpt: 'do-something', required: true, args: 1, 'Do Something' )
}

OptionAccessor options = cli.parse(args)
if(!options) {
  return
}

// print usage if -h, --help, or no argument is given
if(options.h || options.arguments().isEmpty()) {
  println options.arguments().size()
  cli.usage()
  return
} else if (options.d) {
  println options.d
}
```

When I execute the script with the following:

```
groovy cli-test.groovy -d hello
```

I get this output:

```
0
usage: cli-test -d <argument>
 -d,--do-something <arg>   Do Something
 -h,--help                 usage information
```

The `0` is my println is the arguments length. I can't get any options to work other than `h`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `arguments` is the remainder of things _after_ all the params.  So e.g. when calling `groovy cli-test -d hello myfile yourfile`.  then `myfile, yourfile` are the `arguments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that there are no arguments! You've swallowed them all in options.

If you call

```
groovy cli-test.groovy -d hello foo
```

then the arguments() list is `[foo]`

The -d arg is automatically checked for because you made it required, so there's no need to test for it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works this way, but removing:

```
|| options.arguments().isEmpty()
```

from the initial if check makes everything work.